# Space between menu and submenu

Tags: html, css

I have been try to make this dropdown menu work. I want to space to be between the menus.
Tried padding and also the ::after selector.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Hej 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hej 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hej 3</a></li>
             </ul>         
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#menu{
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;

}

#wrapper ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;    
}

#wrapper ul li,#wrapper ul li a, #wrapper ul li ul li, #wrapper li ul li a{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808285;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#wrapper ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    right: -30px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    left: 5px;
}

#wrapper ul li ul li{
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: 0px;
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    display: list-item;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#wrapper ul li a:hover, #wrapper ul li ul li a:hover{
    color: #ba141a;
}

#wrapper ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

#wrapper ul li ul li:hover{ 
    width: 132px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMvg9/1/

Does sombebody knows what the problem is?

Comment: So... just to understand... The system tells you that you need to post at least one code block if you post a jsfiddle, so you put the jsfiddle in the code block? No. [Edit] your question to include *the code itself* in the question, **in addition** to the jsfiddle link, which should *not* be inside of a codeblock.

Comment: Always try to put your code here too. instead of just putting a fiddle. This is because we will not lose this question because of broken link.

Comment: @TheConclusion where do you need the space..? there is enough space between the menu and menu items and among the menu items as far as i can see..

Comment: I simply didn't understand what more space do you need. because I see a space between the menu and sub-menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `margin-top: 20px;` on `#wrapper ul li ul` wich breaks your hover.

Try this next fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/yMvg9/3/

Answer (score 1):

reduce margin on #wrapper ul li ul

```
#wrapper ul li ul {
   margin-top: 9px;
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/yMvg9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Removing/reducing the `margin:20px` from `#wrapper ul li ul` should fix that

```
#wrapper ul li ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
right: -30px;
width: 150px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 0px;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
border-radius: 8px;
left: 5px;
}
```

Would!d become

```
#wrapper ul li ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
margin-top:0px; /* or some other value which suits */
right: -30px;
width: 150px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 0px;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
border-radius: 8px;
left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a Top Margin of 20px to 
`{ #wrapper ul li ul }`

```
#wrapper ul li ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
margin-top: 20px; // Remove of Lessen this one...
right: -30px;
width: 150px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 0px;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
border-radius: 8px;
left: 5px;
}
```

This would probably solve your problem....

[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMvg9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your stylesheet

```
#wrapper ul li ul{ 
     background: none;
}

#wrapper ul li ul li{
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe because the margin is set to 0.
try this working fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/DNQH9/